# Why does the VBA Editor open on its own sometimes?

Tags: vba, outlook, vbe

I created a script in Outlook 2003 VBA that watches for new appointments, and sets them to tentative and no reminder as I create them.  I find that seemingly at random, the VBA editor will open itself.  It doesn't happen when I use the new script, but it did happen this morning when I un-hibernated my laptop, for example.

The editor doesn't pop up any runtime errors or highlight any lines in the script, it's just there as if I had pressed Alt-F11 to launch it.  Sometimes I close other apps and see that it's been sitting back there for a while.

This behavior has only been occurring since I created this new script.  Any ideas why this would occur?

Answer (score 49):

As stated in, [Microsoft Support Center](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829059):

> "This problem occurs only if the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor window
>   is **maximized**."

### *Solution:*

**Un-Maximize** Visual Basic Editor and **close** it.

And you are done!

Comment: Apparently the link to the Microsoft KB page is no longer active, but thankfully the solution "Un-Maximize Visual Basic Editor and close it." solved my problem. Such a simple fix. Thank you very much by the way. This has plagued me for a long time, and happened everytime I reopened Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

If you have previously set breakpoints, it may be that you still have a phantom breakpoint. Try choosing "remove all breakpoints" and see if that clears the problem.

Check also that you have not chosen "Break on all errors" under options, and that your error handler is functioning properly.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Access- "Clear all breakpoings" fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, this is a known issue.  Check out this MS Support link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829059

I have the same problem and found it while I was looking for a solution.  Since it gives no advice, I kept searching and came across your post.  I will come back with an update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The MS page linked by Jaquez hints at the answer; just make sure you don't run the editor maximized, and the problem should go away.  If you restore it to a non-maximized state, then resize it to take up the whole screen, it should remember its position.
It's a pain if you only have a small screen, but on a normal large monitor it works fine, and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, except that it only occurs when I've gone in and unlocked the VBA project for editing and haven't restarted Outlook.  It seems to open up when I get a new email (that's when my VBA runs) so basically I just have to restart Outlook and lock the project back up.

Sorry I don't know what's really causing it, but locking the VBA project should fix the problem...

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to search for the `.otm` file of my VBA project. It was stored under `data\microsoft\outlook`. I closed Outlook and deleted the `.otm` file. Restarted Outlook and it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that I was running into a phantom breakpoint issue with VBA in excel.  Clearing all breakpoints did not work for me, but I resolved it as follows:  Copy all content from offending module into a text file.  Delete module.  Re-create module.  Copy back in all text.  Save.  Phantom breakpoint gone.